# How to concatenate an array in json using JQ

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, export-to-csv, jq

trying to combine the rows. Here is the source

```
{
  "movie_results": [
    {
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        35,
        80
      ],
      "id": 96,
    }
  ]
```

Here is my command line

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/find/tt0092644?&external_source=imdb_id" | jq -r ".movie_results[] | .id, (.genre_ids | join(\",\"))
```

Im getting the following result

```
96
28,35,80
```

how do I make it `96,28,35,80`? By the way im doing this on windows command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small tweak of your jq filter would do the trick:

```
.movie_results[] | [.id, .genre_ids[]] | join(",")
```

(The above line does not take into account your shell's rules for escaping special characters. Have you considered circumventing such issues by using the -f command-line option?)

#### An alternative

Here's an alternative that avoids using double quotes (`"`) in the filter:

```
.movie_results[] | [.id] + .genre_ids | @csv
```